# PHP: time format

Tags: php, time

i know, it should be very easy, but i have problems with the time functions in PHP. I have a string like "1 h 38 min" and i want to convert it to an integer with the numbers of minutes.
Any help or is that to trivial? ;)

Comment: have you tried `preg_match`? (http://php.net/preg_match)

Comment: where is the data coming from?

Comment: it comes from an external source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds more like a job for [sscanf](http://php.net/sscanf) then any of the time functions.

Something like this:

```
<?php

$input = '1 h 38 min';
sscanf($input, '%d h %d min', $hours, $minutes);

$minutes += 60 * $hours;

echo "total minutes: $minutes\n";
```

Comment: If you need more flexibility, have a look at [DateInterval::createFromDateString](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.createfromdatestring.php)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that is a bit more robust than sscanf and a bit more specific to using time (and works with older versions of PHP):

```
$input = '1 d 1 hour 38 min';
$usableInput = trim(str_replace(array(' y ', ' m ', ' d ', ' h ', ' s '), array(' years ', ' months ', ' days ', ' hours ', ' seconds '), " $input "));
$now = time();
$seconds = strtotime("+$usableInput", $now) - $now;
$minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
```